# Restrict payment gateways based on specific product tag in WooCommerce order pay

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, taxonomy-terms

I want to show a payment gateway on the Woocommerce Bookings payment page based on the product's tag and located on the URL extension like: 
`/checkout/order-pay/5759158/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_75uA3d1z1fmCT`

E.g. if the tag's id is "378", then show only "PayPal" gateway and remove other gateways.

I am using [Restrict payment gateways based on taxonomy terms in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622791/restrict-payment-gateways-based-on-taxonomy-terms-in-woocommerce-checkout/57624224#57624224) answer code, that allows to  restricts the payment gateway based on a product tag, but only on the Woocommerce checkout page.

I need to restrict it on the Woocommerce Bookings payment page as well.

How to restrict the payment gateway based on a product tag in Woocommerce Bookings payment page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For order pay pages, you need to loop through order items instead of cart items, to check for product tag terms… To target order pay page use:

```
if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {
```

The following code will disable all payment methods except "paypal" when there is an item that belongs to specific product tag term(s) in order pay page *(and checkout too)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_available_payment_gateways' );
function filter_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Here below your settings
    $taxonomy    = 'product_tag'; // Targeting WooCommerce product tag terms (or "product_cat" for category terms)
    $terms       = array('378'); // Here define the terms (can be term names, slugs or ids)
    $payment_ids = array('paypal'); // Here define the allowed payment methods ids to keep
    $found       = false; // Initializing

    // 1. For Checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
            if ( ! has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. For Order pay
    elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {
        global $wp;

        // Get WC_Order Object from the order id
        $order = wc_get_order( absint($wp->query_vars['order-pay']) );

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            if ( ! has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $found ) {
        foreach ( $available_gateways as $payment_id => $available_gateway ) {
            if ( ! in_array($payment_id, $payment_ids) ) {
                unset($available_gateways[$payment_id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

See: [Conditional Tags in WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Related: [Restrict payment gateways based on taxonomy terms in WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622791/restrict-payment-gateways-based-on-taxonomy-terms-in-woocommerce-checkout/57624224#57624224)

Comment: Thank you Loic - I've tried adding if `( is_checkout() || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {` but it still shows all gateways on the woocommerce order-pay page..

Comment: Thank you Loic! Really appreciated.